# cgroup manager daemon

Tags: services, cgroup

Ubuntu 18.04.1.
Cgroups is not installed.
System jobs admin shows checked:

- Cgroup manager daemon (cgmanager)
- Cgroup manager daemon (cgproxy)

I can not uncheck these items.
How can I remove them?

to show the checked items:
sudo jobs-admin

Comment: I did not  do anything with cgroups. In august came from 16.04. After a while I check the new ubuntu lts.

Comment: In Synaptic cgroups is not installed on my laptop. On my desktop, ubuntu 18.04.1, in Synaptic cgroups is also not installed and no cgroup daemon is running in jobs-admin. No kernel lack.

Comment: hdk@hdklap:~$ sudo jobs-admin